# allow the user to have unique access

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I want a user to save to firebase by their userid.

This is my signup code.

I don't know if it is something I am missing in here to allow the user to have unique access?

```
export class SignupPage {
  signupData = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    passwordRetyped: ''
  };

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.signupData.email = this.navParams.get('email');
  }

  signup() {
    if(this.signupData.password !== this.signupData.passwordRetyped) {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error',
        message: 'Your password and your re-entered password does not match each other.',
    buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();
      return;
    }
    // Firebase Signup Code
      this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupData.email, this.signupData.password)
    .then(auth => {
      // Could do something with the Auth-Response
      console.log(auth);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Handle error
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error',
        message: err.message,
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: By default, Firebase doesn't save the users like the other data so you will never see the users appear in the database. If you want to add some user data you have to add this data manually in the database. Is that what you want?

Comment: what does console.log(auth) gives you?

Comment: Hi Maxine, at the moment the users login to the same app. However, the app is a diary so I want the user to save their own data to firebase by their unique userid?

Comment: Hi Kevin, the login is currently workin but all users login to the same application. As I mentioned above I want users to save by their unique userID. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.